# Como definir uma rota ou caminho absoluto na url do javascript utilizando Laravel 10?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, apache, rotas

Do jeito que meu código está atualmente roda sem problemas no servidor local de desenvolvimento do Laravel, porém quando coloco no servidor Apache/XAMPP ele para de funcionar  e retorna o erro **"GET http://10.32.2.15:8080/dataAjax?_type=query 404 (Not Found)"** quando vou inspecionar no Chrome.

trecho de código javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $('.employee_id').select2({
        placeholder: 'Digite o nome do responsável.',
        ajax: {
            url: '/dataAjax',
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 250,
            processResults: function(data) {
                return {
                    results: $.map(data, function(item) {
                        return {
                            text: item.nome,
                            id: item.id
                        }
                    })
                };
            },
            cache: true
        }
    });
});
```

Que está no meu projeto laravel 10, na pasta public/js/funcoes e precisa acessar a função dataAjax  da Controller, VehiclesController, abaixo:

```
public function dataAjax(Request $request)
{
    $data = [];
    if($request->has('q')){
        $search = $request->q;
        $data = Employee::select("id","nome")
                ->where('nome','LIKE',"%$search%")
                ->get();
    }
    return response()->json($data);
}
```

Quem tem a rota definida em web.php como:

```
Route::get('/dataAjax', [VehiclesController::class,'dataAjax']);
```

Comment: 10.x.x.x é sempre endereço de rede privada, nunca um IP público. Você deve ter deixado sobrar isso em algum lugar – config, variável de ambiente...

Comment: O sistema vai rodar em uma rede privada mesmo. Instalei o XAMPP na minha máquina local para testes.